# AWS Amplify React AzureAD federatedSignIn

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I implementing Auth for an internal Single Page App using React, Cognito userpool, Azure AD.

There are lots of information and I am not able to connect the dots to make the entire application to work.

I have set up AWS Cognito User Pool and Azure AD. I followed https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-amazon-cognito-for-federated-authentication-using-azure-ad/

On React side, I am following guide from Amplify
https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/add-social-provider/#full-samples
I have "aws-amplify": "^6.0.4",

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import { Hub } from "aws-amplify/utils";
import { signInWithRedirect, signOut, getCurrentUser } from "aws-amplify/auth";
import { AuthUser } from "aws-amplify/auth";

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      //  Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
      userPoolId: "XX-xxxx-#_XXXXXXXXXX",
      // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
      userPoolClientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
      // identityPoolId: "XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab",
      // OPTIONAL - This is used when autoSignIn is enabled for Auth.signUp
      // 'code' is used for Auth.confirmSignUp, 'link' is used for email link verification
      signUpVerificationMethod: "code", // 'code' | 'link'
      loginWith: {
        // OPTIONAL - Hosted UI configuration
        oauth: {
          domain:
            "https://my-userpool.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com",
          scopes: ["email", "openid"],
          redirectSignIn: ["http://localhost:3000/"],
          redirectSignOut: ["http://localhost:3000/"],
          responseType: "code", // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function RootApp() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<AuthUser | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload }) => {
      switch (payload.event) {
        case "signInWithRedirect":
          getUser();
          break;
        case "signInWithRedirect_failure":
          console.log("An error has ocurred during the Oauth flow.");
          break;
      }
    });

    getUser();

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const getUser = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
      setUser(currentUser);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      console.log("Not signed in");
    }
  };

  return user !== null ? (
    <AuthenticatedApp user={user}></AuthenticatedApp>
  ) : (
    <UnauthenticatedApp />
  );
}

function UnauthenticatedApp() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <button
          onClick={
            () =>
              signInWithRedirect({ provider: { custom: "MyAD" } }) //MyAD is identity provider name in AWS cognito
          }
        >
          Log in
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

interface Props {
  user: AuthUser;
}

function AuthenticatedApp({ user }: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
      <div>{user?.username}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After I click on Sign In, I get below page.
[image]

I really appreciate if anyone can point to to right direction to resolve this.

Comment: Could you not write `amplify add auth` via the CLI to set it up?

Comment: trying to avoid amplify cli. I do not know what that does and how that works with FederatedSignIn. Lot of examples I see is without FederatedSignIn. I am also not sure how to move my changes to different environment once I am done with my testing. I really prefer that I do everything manually in AWS side  and write react code with necessary config from AWS.

Comment: What you do is link your amplify environments to code commit branches. Then as you push new changes, you can choose a front-end only update, or full-stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "https://" from  domain:"https://my-userpool.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com", and verify that the redirectSignIn and redirectSignOut in Amplify.configure({Auth: {Cognito: {...}}}) are the exactly the same (https vs http, etc) as you configured in the Cognito App Client.